# Can't start Ruby server, following book "Beginning Rails 4"

Tags: ruby, server

I have been following directions in this book (and I made sure I copied everything over correctly). The example I'm working on is making a simple application by first generating a controller, creating an action, and then creating a template. This is just a simple "hello world" example.

The problem: When I enter "rails server" (while in the app folder) in my Terminal, I get a bunch of stuff, but it starts off with an undefined method error. I am posting the stuff below:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:hello alexcrisan$ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `  get' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fe383be0a00> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in `draw'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/bin/spring:14:in `require'
    from /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/Beginning Rails 4/hello/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure why it's doing this, so any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the content of this file `hello/config/routes.rb`

Comment: The first line of the trace points to line 2 of the routes file. Please post that file.

Comment: The title of the book tells that it covers Rails 4. But you generated a Rails 5 application. I would suggest to start over with a Rails 4 application or to buy a new book.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. It did end up being because I had two blank spaces in front of "get."

Hello::Application.routes.draw do
get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says undefined method `  get' for . 
This is due to the extra spaces before 'get'. Remove them and I think you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. This was it... not sure why the spaces matter? The spaces are supposed to make the code look more legible, and I thought they were ignored.

Comment: Spaces inside quotes would matter, I think.

Comment: Hello::Application.routes.draw do
get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end

Well there are no quotes around "get." I am using quotes to signal that "get" is a keyword but there are no quotes around it in the code so the spaces should not matter. In any programming language spaces don't matter.